# Specifying SQL variable to xquery exist method to check if value is in given set of values

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery, sqlxml

I am trying to query an XML column to return all rows where an attribute is in a list of possible values.

XQuery allows something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE xml_col.exist('//Field.[@name=("value1","value2","value3")]') = 1
```

which would return the number of records that have a Field with attribute @name set to either "value1", "value2" or "value3".

What I'd like to do is write a concise query that could handle the set  "value1", "value2", "value3" as an input parameter, e.g.

```
DECLARE @list NVARCHAR(100)

SET @list = '("value1","value2","value3")'

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE xml_col.exist('//Field.[@name=sql:variable("@list")]') = 1
```

which, of course, is invalid. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simplest way to do it is (if your name could not contain `,`):

```
declare @list nvarchar(max) = ',value1,value2,value3,'

select count(*) 
from test
where xml_col.exist('//Field[contains(sql:variable("@list"), concat(",", @name, ","))]') = 1;
```

or SQL way:

```
select count(*) 
from test
where
    exists
    (
         select 1 from xml_col.nodes('//Field') as T(C)
         where T.C.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
    )
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba1b1/11)

Comment: thanks, updated the answer, took a wrong one from sql fiddle, +1 for you

Comment: Thanks Roman, that is exactly what I wanted! I think I'll use the first version. That's a pretty neat trick.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in this case it would be easier to check on the SQL side:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE xml_col.value('(//Field/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

At least this would work if there is only one `Field` element in your XML, otherwise it would get a bit more complex.

Comment: Hi FrankPl, yes, that would work for only the first Field. I should have specified though that there are multiple Fields in each xml record, and I'd like to evaluate all of them.

Comment: You would then probably have to use an approach using cross apply like described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/04/24/flattening-xml-data-in-sql-server.aspx and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalla/archive/2005/12/15/504311.aspx

Comment: Another approach, staying within XML, could be to build one XML object containing the search values and the value of the column, and then apply the exist on that, something like `xml_col.query(/* something building one XML from the column content plus the search string */).exist(/* something working within this XML */)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try following construct:

```
select count(1)
from [table] t
where exists (
    select 1 from (values ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')) l(v)
    where t.xml_col.exist('//Field[@name=sql:column("l.v")]') = 1);
```

Also it can be used with table variable or table valued parameter in the following way:

```
declare @list table (value varchar(100))
insert into @list values ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')
```

or

```
create type ListOfValues as table (value varchar(100))
GO
declare @list ListOfValues
insert into @list values ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')
```

and then

```
select count(1)
from [table] t
where exists(select 1 from @list l
    where t.xml_col.exist('//Field[@name=sql:column("l.value")]') = 1);
```